# Prove that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{y-2x}$ doesn't exist.

Tags: limits

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{y-2x}$ with real domain. Every path I choose in real plane tends to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $y=2x+x^2$? Then  $xy=2x^2+x^3$ and $y-2x=x^2$, limit $2$.

Comment: Or $y=2 x+x^3$ with $x\ne 0$. Then $|x y/(y-2 x)|$ goes to infinity.